# Angularjs how to send data from one module to other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a module like this

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('build', ['ngSanitize', 'uihelper']);

  app.controller('buildctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.attributes = {"color": "#efefef", "width": "20px" .... };
...
```

My uihelper module looks like this..

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('uihelper', []);

  app.controller('uictrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = // I want $scope.attributes here

...
```

Can I access the `$scope.attributes` in the module 1 in module 2, will module 2 observe the dynamic changes made to the `$scope.attributes` in module 1

I just started using angularjs. I appreciate any help.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu So in module 2 can I use $scope.attributes??

Comment: In the first one, where does your `$scope` come from? I don't think it will exist in this context

Comment: @devqon my mistake the $scope.sttributes is inside the a controller...I will update it..

Comment: They are both separate controllers, so they both have their own `$scope`, which will not share data between the two. You might be able to use `$rootScope`, which is a shared scope in the application

Answer (score 0):

Create service with method, inject service wherever you need

```
app.service('ConstantsService', function () {
    return {
        getAttributes: {"color": "#efefef", "width": "20px"}
    }
})


app.controller('uictrl', function ($scope, ConstantsService) {
    $scope.data = ConstantsService.getAttributes();
})
```